# How can I have a SSH banner appear BEFORE the "login as:" prompt?

Tags: centos, openssh, sshd

CentOS 5.x

When I enable the `Banner /path/to/banner` parameter in my sshd config file, the banner displays AFTER the `login as:` prompt.

For example:

```
login as: foo
***********************************************************
Test Example SSH Banner Text
This is a test
Example 12345
***********************************************************
foo@1.2.3.4's password:
```

Admittedly this isn't an issue for ssh connections that connect with a username already specified prior to connecting.  But for ssh connections that don't have a user name preselected, users see this upon connecting:

```
login as:
```

Is there any way to get the banner to display BEFORE the `login as:` prompt?

Comment: What client are you using to connect?

Comment: @flup PuTTY on a Windows workstation.

Comment: Don't let the title of that dup fool you, my answer explains that this isn't possible.

Comment: @slm that probably explains why I didn't think there were any matches when searching for similar questions. ;-)

Comment: @MikeB - yes that Q was easier for me to find but probably not anyone else 8-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by your client rather than the server.  The `login as:` prompt is PuTTY's own, and it won't display the banner before a username is entered.  If you're using shared keys, then the banner will be displayed at key exchange time, even if the key goes on to be rejected.

Comment: I don't know about you but my PuTTY sessions actually do display the contents of `/etc/issue`. It is still up to the client whether they want to actually display that, though.

Comment: It does display the banner, but only after the username is entered; I think the OP wanted the banner to appear before the prompt.

Comment: You're talking about `/etc/motd` there, I'm referring to `/etc/issue` which is the pre-login banner intended to tell people the system is being monitored, etc.

Comment: Nono, we're talking about the same thing -- my PuTTY displays `/etc/issue` after entering the usernanme, but before entering the password.